# Getting rid of Buzzards

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my fortress, Buzzards are a pest and they always seem to find a way to get themselves caged. I would like to know if there is a way to kill them automatically (or at least without me having to manually kill each of them).

A complex solution isn't a big problem for me as long as it isn't very repetitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could let some hunters loose and see if they take down the buzzards frequently enough for your liking.

You could also have a squad of marksdwarves under orders to patrol the area where the buzzards congregate, but I think you'll have to issue kill orders manually in order to kill the buzzards (best done from the list instead of selecting with the cursor).

You could chain up some dogs in the problem areas and they will scare away or at least fight most wildlife pests. They also make handy kobold/elf/goblin detectors so it's not a bad idea to do this anyway.

If you're truly desperate, you can edit your raws so that they have no brains and die instantly on spawning. In your save folder go to /raws/objects/creature_birds_new.txt and find the line that says `[BODY:HUMANOID_ARMLESS_NECK:2WINGS:2EYES:2LUNGS:HEART:GUTS:ORGANS:GIZZARD:HUMANOID_JOINTS:THROAT:NECK:SPINE:BRAIN:SKULL:4TOES:BEAK:TONGUE:RIBCAGE]`. Remove the :BRAIN: part and see if that helps. I would recommend making a backup of your save files before doing this.

Comment: thanks for the prevention suggestions,do you have any funny ideas about what to do with the already caged ones?

Comment: Breed them! Honestly they're pretty worthless animals. Most of the time they don't even produce bones when killed. They might be worth domesticating and using for leather production (who wouldn't want a buzzard skin cloak?) or as military practice if you don't domesticate them.

Comment: Targets for your non-legendary marksdwarves may be the most valuable use for them.

Answer (score 2):

Hunter dwarves will automatically try to kill anything that is edible, including animals *other* than buzzards. If your wilderness doesn't include dangerous animals, hunters should solve your problem nicely, as long as you keep them supplied with bolts.